# svn export to tgz file

Tags: svn, export, tar

How do I export a svn project directly to a .tgz file? I don't want to create a directory with all of the subdirectories and code, just want it as a .tgz file.

Similar to

```
 git archive --remote {git_location} --format tgz {git_ref} > {archive_file}'
```

Comment: I think you have to export to a directory and then tar it up separate. I don't think there is a direct path between the two. It looks like at least one person created a script to do so: https://narfation.org/2009/01/08/creating-recreatable-tar-gz-from-svn

Answer (score 0):

```
'svn export {svn_url} {some_path} ; tar -czvf {archive_filename} {some_path}
```